# div (if it has another div inside) + div { }

Tags: html, css

How to make a rule that will do something like this:

.container .unit:first-child(if it has inside div.box1.extra) + .box2 { top: 50px;}

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="unit">
       <div class="box1 extra"><!-- content --></div>
   </div>

   <div class="unit">
       <div class="box1"><!-- content --></div>
   </div>

   <div class="box2"><!-- content --></div>                 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible with CSS at present.  What you are referring to is DOM traversal with CSS.  What you can do is simply declare the rule anyway.

```
.container .unit:first-child .box1.extra + .box2 { top: 50px;}
```

if the `.box2` element does not exist, nothing will change.  for the units that do have a `.box2`, the rule will apply.

EDIT:  Note that this only works if `.box2` is a child of `.unit`.  If `.unit` and `.box2` are siblings, this unfortunately impossible.

Comment: @DanilaBelov Ah, I see it now.  I didn't look close enough to the markup.  Would it be possible to place box2 inside of the first unit element?  You could then still apply `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` (as I assume you are) and make sure `.unit` is `position:static`.  This will most likely be exactly the same as if it was a child of `unit`.